# javascript dynamic function call undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

## The function savefromtextarea() & varialbe globe is undefined wen called on click of save button...

This one part of my code...I need to access the save from texarea method when clicked on the save text button...when I try to invoke the saveFromTextArea method its throws globe is undefined but globe variable is global variable ...

```
    ME.ZFP.annotaion.Text = function () { //function to annotate the text

var canvas = myscreen.getTempCanvas().ele;
var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
var global = this;

$(canvas).mousedown(function(e){ //on mouse down event 

    if ($('#textAreaPopUp').length === 0) {
        
        var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft + $(canvas).position().left;
        var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

        //append a text area box to the canvas where the user clicked to enter in a comment
        var textArea = "<div id='textAreaPopUp' style='position:absolute;top:"+mouseY+"px;left:"+mouseX+"px;z-index:30;'><input type='text' id='textareaTest' ></input>";
     //Click on save buttom global.saveTextFromArea undefined
        var saveButton = "<input type='button' value='save' id='saveText' onclick='global.saveTextFromArea("+mouseY+","+mouseX+");'></div>";
        var appendString = textArea + saveButton;
        $("#container").append(appendString);
    } 
});
//Function to be called 
this.saveTextFromArea = function(y,x){
        //get the value of the textarea then destroy it and the save button
        var text = $('textarea#textareaTest').val();
        $('textarea#textareaTest').remove();
        $('#saveText').remove();
        $('#textAreaPopUp').remove();
    
}

   }
```

Thanks
Ajain

Comment: I don't see `saveTextFromArea` (or `savefromtextarea`) defined anywhere. What exactly is your problem and question? Obviously your code example is not complete, so it is difficult for us (if not impossible) to help you, since there are some many unknowns. And *guessing* is a waste of our and your time. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo that shows what is wrong and clarify your question.

Comment: What does "invoked dynamically" mean? Does the implied "invoked statically" (whatever that would mean) work?

Comment: Felix King ... please refer to modified code..

Answer (score 0):

Well your code has some errors, fixed in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcweg/).
You forgot `});` at the very end of the code.
Lastly (nitpicking) I corrected:
`if ($('#textAreaPopUp').length == 0)` to
`if ($('#textAreaPopUp').length === 0)`

But.. does this corrected code fix your problem?

Comment: What are the errors? How can they be fixed? If the link is down, your answer is useless.

Answer (score 0):

An inline event handler like your `onclick='...'` can only reference globally scoped variables and functions, but if your variable named `global` is declared inside a function (inside a document.ready handler, for example) then it is not global and the inline attribute event handler can't see it.